# Javascript Animation in HTML Canvas - Can't keep animation within borders

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working with a javascript animation that shows ripples in water in html canvas.

This is the javascript code  and the [jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/esteewhy/5ht3b/6/)

```js
(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
        /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        width = 400,
        height = 400,
        half_width = width >> 1,
        half_height = height >> 1,
        size = width * (height + 2) * 2,
        delay = 30,
        oldind = width,
        newind = width * (height + 3),
        riprad = 3,
        ripplemap = [],
        last_map = [],
        ripple,
        texture,
        line_width = 20,
        step = line_width * 2, 
        count = height / line_width;
        
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    
    
    with (ctx) {
        fillStyle = '#a2ddf8';
        fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        
        fillStyle = '#07b';
        save();
        rotate(-0.785);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fillRect(-width, i * step, width * 3, line_width);
        }
        
        restore();
    }
    
    texture = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    ripple = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        last_map[i] = ripplemap[i] = 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Main loop
     */
    function run() {
        newframe();
        ctx.putImageData(ripple, 0, 0);
    }
    
    /**
     * Disturb water at specified point
     */
    function disturb(dx, dy) {
        dx <<= 0;
        dy <<= 0;
        
        for (var j = dy - riprad; j < dy + riprad; j++) {
            for (var k = dx - riprad; k < dx + riprad; k++) {
                ripplemap[oldind + (j * width) + k] += 128;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Generates new ripples
     */
    function newframe() {
        var a, b, data, cur_pixel, new_pixel, old_data;
        
        var t = oldind; oldind = newind; newind = t;
        var i = 0;
        
        // create local copies of variables to decrease
        // scope lookup time in Firefox
        var _width = width,
            _height = height,
            _ripplemap = ripplemap,
            _last_map = last_map,
            _rd = ripple.data,
            _td = texture.data,
            _half_width = half_width,
            _half_height = half_height;
        
        for (var y = 0; y < _height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
                var _newind = newind + i, _mapind = oldind + i;
                data = (
                    _ripplemap[_mapind - _width] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind + _width] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind - 1] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind + 1]) >> 1;
                    
                data -= _ripplemap[_newind];
                data -= data >> 5;
                
                _ripplemap[_newind] = data;

                //where data=0 then still, where data>0 then wave
                data = 1024 - data;
                
                old_data = _last_map[i];
                _last_map[i] = data;
                
                if (old_data != data) {
                    //offsets
                    a = (((x - _half_width) * data / 1024) << 0) + _half_width;
                    b = (((y - _half_height) * data / 1024) << 0) + _half_height;
    
                    //bounds check
                    if (a >= _width) a = _width - 1;
                    if (a < 0) a = 0;
                    if (b >= _height) b = _height - 1;
                    if (b < 0) b = 0;
    
                    new_pixel = (a + (b * _width)) * 4;
                    cur_pixel = i * 4;
                    
                    _rd[cur_pixel] = _td[new_pixel];
                    _rd[cur_pixel + 1] = _td[new_pixel + 1];
                    _rd[cur_pixel + 2] = _td[new_pixel + 2];
                }
                
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    canvas.onmousemove = function(/* Event */ evt) {
        disturb(evt.offsetX || evt.layerX, evt.offsetY || evt.layerY);
    };
    
    setInterval(run, delay);
    
    // generate random ripples
    var rnd = Math.random;
    setInterval(function() {
        disturb(rnd() * width, rnd() * height);
    }, 700);
    
})();
```

The issue is the ripple spills over from one side of the canvas and animates on the opposite side, I want to keep them from moving into the opposite sides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Stopping waves at edges**

To stop the propagation of the waves across the edges you need to limit the function that adds the disturbance so that it does not write past the edges.

So change...

```
function disturb(dx, dy) {
    dx <<= 0;
    dy <<= 0;
    for (var y = dy - riprad; y < dy + riprad; y++) {
        for (var x = dx - riprad; x < dx + riprad; x++) {
            ripplemap[oldind + (y * width) + x] += 128;
        }
    }
}
```

to...

```
function disturb(dx, dy) {
    dx <<= 0;
    dy <<= 0;
    for (var y = dy - riprad; y < dy + riprad; y++) {
        for (var x = dx - riprad; x < dx + riprad; x++) {
            // don't go past the edges.
            if(y >= 0 && y < height && x >= 0 && x < width){
                ripplemap[oldind + (y * width) + x] += 128;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you also need to change the wave propagation that is in the function `newFrame`. The propagation is controlled by the value in `data`. A value of zero means no wave and no propagation. So test if the pixel is on the edge. If the pixel is an edge pixel then just stop the wave by setting `data` to zero. To save CPU cycles I have added to vars `h`, `w` that are `height - 1` and `width - 1` so you don't have to perform the subtraction twice for every pixel.

Change the code in the function `newFrame` from...

```
    for (var y = 0; y < _height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
            var _newind = newind + i, _mapind = oldind + i;
            data = (
                _ripplemap[_mapind - _width] + 
                _ripplemap[_mapind + _width] + 
                _ripplemap[_mapind - 1] + 
                _ripplemap[_mapind + 1]) >> 1;
            }
```

To...

```
    var w = _width - 1; // to save having to subtract 1 for each pixel
    var h = _height - 1; // dito
    for (var y = 0; y < _height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
            var _newind = newind + i, _mapind = oldind + i;
            // is the pixel on the edge
            if(y === 0 || x === 0 || y === h || x === w){
                data = 0; // yes edge pixel so stop propagation.
            }else{
                // not on the edge so just do as befor.
                data = (
                    _ripplemap[_mapind - _width] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind + _width] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind - 1] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind + 1]) >> 1;
            }
```

This is not perfect as it will dampen the waves bouncing from the sides but you don't have much CPU time so it is a good solution.

**Some notes.**

Use `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setInterval(run, delay)` to time the animation as you will cause some devices to crash the page with the code you currently have, if the device can not handle the CPU load. `requestAnimationFrame` will stop this happening.

Change the run function to

```
function run() {
    newframe();
    ctx.putImageData(ripple, 0, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
}
```

At bottom of code remove `setInterval(run,delay);` and add

```
requestAnimationFrame(run);
```

And change the second `setInterval` to

```
var drops = function() {
    disturb(rnd() * width, rnd() * height);
    setTimeout(drops,700)
};
drops();
```

**NEVER** use `setInterval`, especially for this type of CPU intensive code. You will cause many machines to crash the page. Us setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame instead.

Also remove the `with` statement where you create the texture.